# plotly: wait until plot function created a plot on the plotly server

Tags: python, plotly

I am using the `plotly` `plot` function to create plots like:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
plot_url = py.plot(data_json, filename=name)
```

Is there a way to get notified when the `plot` function is done creating a plot on the plotly server? (Or make the call blocking)